# how to set default value of an many2one field?

Tags: default, odoo-9

I am new in odoo 9 comunity.I have created many2one filed in my custom module that inherit sale.order.line and I would like to set default value for that many2one field with the condition  fto call the funscion is the product that come with bill of material. what are steps to get that purpose? thank for your times.

Answer (score 0):

Take this example, here i am taking products belongs a warehouse selected in `sale.order` and return this to `product_id` in `sale.order.line` .

```
obj_location = self.pool.get('stock.warehouse').browse(cr, uid, warehouse_id, context=context).lot_stock_id.id
obj_inventory = self.pool.get('stock.quant').search(cr, uid, [('location_id', '=', obj_location)])
product_ids = []
products_qty = []
    for obj in obj_inventory:
            obj_products_id = self.pool.get('stock.quant').browse(cr, uid, obj)
            product_ids.append(obj_products_id.product_id.id)
return {'domain': {'product_id': [('id', 'in', product_ids)]}}
```

Comment: As you see in the following code, my purpose is when i create a sale order, if products [that is created with Bill of material(BOM)] the default value for width_id filed will automatically set, if product come without BOM, the function get False, sorry because my low level of English, thank for replying.

Comment: Actually i start to learn about programing so i have no idea about the possible way to get the purpose. please give me a hand to list out the steps to get the purpose. Thank you, sorry because my bad English, i hope you can get the meaning.

Comment: if i understand your problem, you need to fetch the ids of products  and return domain. example `return {'domain': {'product_id': [('id', 'in', product_ids)]}}` here `products_ids` is the id browsed from another model. i believe this is what you are looking

Comment: could you please help me to wirte out full formof the funcsion, thanks alot

Comment: i think that you get exactly the right meaning that I have intend to sent you, I am new on programing and if you dont mind, please give me a hand to tell me an example to resolve the problem?

Comment: i edited my answer with an  example hope you find a clue to get what you want

Comment: which model should i add your code ? my custom module that inherited the sale.order.line or i do need to create an other module that inherit bom.mrp model?

Comment: this is not the code that you need. its just a example. you should browse the product ids having bom. Find the relation between `product.product` and `bom.model` from tables

Answer (score 0):

class unit_rate(models.Model):

```
_name = "sale.order.line.width"

name = fields.Char(u'Tên', required=True)
rate = fields.Float(u'Hệ số', required=True, default=1)
unit_id = fields.Many2one('product.uom', string=u'Đơn vị', required=True)
description = fields.Text(u'Chú thích')
```

class SaleLine(models.Model):

```
_inherit = "sale.order.line"
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals['rate'] < 1:
        raise UserError(_(u'Không thể đưa vào hệ số nhỏ hơn 0'))
    return super(unit_rate, self).create(vals)

_inherit = "sale.order.line"

width_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line.width', u'Kiểu tính')
```